# reusing structs in another struct in golang

Tags: go, struct

I have two structs in golang as below

```
type Data struct {
    Name          string
    Description   string
    HasMore   bool
}

type DataWithItems struct {
    Name          string
    Description   string
    HasMore      bool
    Items    []Items
}
```

At most `DataWithItems` struct can be rewritten as

```
 type DataWithItems struct {
        Info Data
        Items []Items
    }
```

But the above make it difficult when decoding a json object into `DataWithItems`. I know this can be solved with inheritance in other programming languages but `Is there a way I can solve this in Go?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "embed" the one struct into the other:

```
type Items string

type Data struct {
    Name        string
    Description string
    HasMore     bool
}

type DataWithItems struct {
    Data // Notice that this is just the type name
    Items []Items
}

func main() {
    d := DataWithItems{}
    d.Data.Name = "some-name"
    d.Data.Description = "some-description"
    d.Data.HasMore = true
    d.Items = []Items{"some-item-1", "some-item-2"}

    result, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println(string(result))
}
```

this prints

```
{"Name":"some-name","Description":"some-description","HasMore":true,"Items":["some-item-1","some-item-2"]}
```

Comment: You can also reference the fields of `Data` in `DataWithItems` directly as long as there are no name conflicts. For example `d.Name` works.

Comment: @HenryWoody Very true! I can never tell which I prefer for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one struct - DataWithItems and sometimes leave items blank